# Examples of group $G=N \rtimes H$ where $N$ and $H$ are as below

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, ergodic-theory

I am searching for examples of connected locally compact group $G = N \rtimes H$, where $N$ is a simply connected nilpotent non-abelian Lie group, $H$ is linear reductive and $H$ operates on $N$ without non-trivial fixed points. Please enlighten me.

P.S. I added the ergodic theory tag because I believe such groups are seen there.

This is also posted in stackexchange.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037426/examples-of-non-abelian-simply-connected-nilpotent-lie-groups

Comment: I would try to stick $H$ into the title somehow, because without it the question seems really trivial (all groups of upper triangular matrices are contractible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the nilpotent group $N={\mathbb R} \rtimes {\mathbb R}^2$ (the group of $3\times 3$ upper triangular unipotent matrices with real coefficients. If $v,w \in {\mathbb R}^2$, then their commutator $[v,w]$ in $N$ is simply the wedge $v\wedge w \in \wedge ^2 {\mathbb R}^2\simeq {\mathbb R}$.

The group $H=SL(2,{\mathbb R})$ operates on $N$  since it preserves the symplectic form $v\wedge w$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: Is it obvious that $H$ acts without fixed points?

Comment: If the action of $H$ on $N$ is as follows: for $h \in H, (t,v) \in N, h.(t,v) = (t,hv)$ then $H$ fixes $\mathbb{R} \rtimes \{(0,0)\}$ ! What exactly is your action?

Comment: The above action is symplectic automorphism. Apply inversion further to get desired action.

Comment: OK. You replace $SL(2,{\mathbb R})$ by $H=GL(2,{\mathbb R})$ except that on $\mathbb R$ the group $H$ acts via determinant, and hence does not fix anything except identity. It acts on ${\mathbb R}^2$ preserving the symplectic form up to sclars, and hence still acts on $N$.

Comment: $N$ is not a semidirect product $\mathbf{R}\rtimes\mathbf{R}^2$; I don't know if you mean to think of it as a central (not split) extension with kernel $\mathbf{R}$ and quotient $\mathbf{R}^2$, or as a semidirect product with kernel $\mathbf{R}^2$ and quotient $\mathbf{R}$. Anyway, it works.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, you are right. I do not need $N$ to be a semi-direct product. There is an exact sequence  $$ 0 \rightarrow {\mathbb R} \rightarrow N \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow 1$$. The group $GL(2,{\mathbb R})$ acts on the exact sequence.

Comment: Is every central(non-split) extension with kernel $\mathbb{R}$ and quotient $\mathbb{R^2}$ simply connected nilpotent Lie group?

Comment: @Mambo: yes. The simple connectedness follows from the homotopy exact sequence since $N \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2$ is a locally trivial fibration with fibre $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $H=T$ to be the maximal torus in a (quasi)split reductive group $\Gamma$, $N$ to be the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup containing $T$, and the action is by conjugation. If some element $x\in N$ is fixed by $T$ then it centralizes $T$ and so must be in $T$, which is impossible.

Comment: You need to exclude the edge case that $N$ is abelian (e.g., $SL_n$ works for $n \geq 3$). I think more generally $H$ can be taken to be a Levi factor of a parabolic subgroup $P=L \ltimes U$ with the same caveat (your example is the case $P=B = T\ltimes N$).